# Concatenating new line character char(13) in pySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We are getting error while adding next line `char(13)` in pyspark `concat` function below is sample code

```
spark.sql("select CONCAT('Vinay',CHAR(13),'AGARWAL') from tempTable")
```

Is `CHAR(13)` not supported under concat function of pyspark?

Comment: Please share the error you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I found the issue and the solution. Its not taking char(30) instead its taking \n to add next line character. below is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue and the solution. Its not taking char(30) instead its taking \n to add next line character. below is the solution.

spark.sql("select CONCAT('Vinay\n','AGARWAL') from tempTable")

Comment: It adds a space if you try the same in Hive. `SELECT CONCAT('Vinay\n','AGARWAL') AS full_name`

Comment: I think "\n" is supposed to be more portable.